# Align rotation of text with straight connector in Visio 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, alignment, microsoft-visio-2016

I have a straight connector between two elements in Visio 2016. I'd like to label it but if I try to add label and rotate it doesn't 'snap' in aligned position.

Is there a way to align it other than increasing the finesse of grid and manually rotate to desired location?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking about the rotation of the cinnector or of the text. My answer below tells you how to align the text with the line.

Answer (score 1):

To align the text with the connector set the section **Text Transform** cell **TxtAngle** to **=ATAN2(EndY-BeginY,EndX-BeginX)**

Comment: this is great! saved me a lot of manual fiddling